# How can I delete a certificate that got restored from a backup under iOS 10/11?

Tags: iphone, backup, certificate, ios

With iOS, certificates are installed as part of profiles. Deleting a certificate means removing the profile.

When an iPhone with profiles is backed up, and then the backup is restored to a new device, the profiles are no longer visible under Settings > General > Profiles. So, they can't be deleted via the usual way.

The certificates however get restored to the device. One can see them e.g. under Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings.

Hence my question: How can these certificates be deleted from the device?

Comment: Idea: maybe it's possible to create a new profile overwriting the previous one, then delete that and see if the certificate disappears with it. Maybe it's the payloadIdentifier as noted here https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf#page5

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found a certificate in my iOS device's Certificate Trust Settings. And it was not be found in Profiles. Finally I remove it by add the cert file again, and then I can found and remove it in Profiles.

At first, I can't found the cert file, because this CA was installed years ago. So I did these things:

1. Backup iPhone to Mac, View backup file by some software (I used iMazing)
2. Find TrustStore.sqlite3 in Backup/KeychainDomain/ and export it to HOME DIR.
3. Use this project https://github.com/ADVTOOLS/ADVTrustStore to export certfile

   ```
   ./iosCertTrustManager.py -t ~/TrustStore.sqlite3 -e ~/foo.crt
   ```
4. Airdrop or Email this crt file to iOS device, and install it.
5. Find it in Settings > General > Profiles and Remove it.
6. It disappear in "Certificate Trust Settings"

Done.

Comment: Great! I used iPhone Backup Explorer for extracting the TrustStore.sqlite3 from an old backup - the free version was enough for extracting this single file (see: https://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/guides/itunes-backup-recovery/#view-itunes-backup). Then was able to remove the Onavo certificate entry using the suggested steps above.

Comment: This solution worked as a charm! I manually found the TrustStore.sqlite3 in my backup (I don't trust those apps that do that), then followed your instructions.

Comment: OMG @mgbaozi - THANK YOU! i was real nervous to do it cause i'm not a programmer nor Terminal user, but i followed your instructions and it worked perfectly! i too use iMazing but i switched to iCloud backups last year, but it found an old backup which had what i needed. my stuck cert w/no profile was an adblocker app that doesn't work anymore called Luna. glad to finally eradicate that from my system. so much appreciation!

Comment: man you saved my life!!!! As of today, this trick still works!!

Comment: Can also confirm that these instructions still work for iOS 14.6, macOS 11.4. The free (demo) version of iMazing is sufficient for doing this.

Comment: This may have been solved with iOS 15 and a transition to a new device (or maybe just a backup and restore to the same device). I used my Mac to backup my iPhone running iOS 15 which still had certificates with no profile associated. When I restored it to my new phone those certificates were no longer present. I had done the backup, intending to follow the steps above, but was happy to see the certs are gone.

Comment: worked for me with ios 14.8

Comment: worked for me with ios 15.1.1

Comment: @Ian: [How did you manually view the contents of the backup without a 3rd party app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451511/how-to-view-iphone-backup-contents-without-a-3rd-party-app)

Comment: This worked on iOS 16.1.1. **[Don't forget to install]** If it doesn't work, make sure that after downloading the certificate, you actually go into Settings and "Install" it. If it is listed under "Downloaded profile" and you hit the "Remove Downloaded Profile" it won't actually remove the profile. You must install it (it will ask for a passcode) and _then_ hit the "Remove Profile". **[Python 2 required]** Also note that the script requires python2. It will fail on the latest python (3).

Comment: @Senseful sorry I honestly can't recall. I might've found some CLI utility on github that did the trick.